# How to construct example satisfying certain properties in group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, frattini-subgroup

The background problem is exercise 22 in section 6.1 Abstract Algebra by Dummit & Foote:

> When $G$ is a finite group prove that if $N\unlhd{G}$ then $\Phi(N)\leq{\Phi(G)}$. Give an explicit example where this containment does not hold if N is not normal in $G$. ($\Phi(G)$ is the *Frattini group subgroup* of $G$, i.e. the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$.)

The proof of the containment when $N$ is normal in G is:

Suppose that $M$ is any maximal subgroup of $G$, if $\Phi(N)\nleq M$, then $N \nleq M$, since $N\unlhd G$ and $\Phi(N) $ is characteristic in $N$, $\Phi(N) \unlhd G$, so $\Phi(N)M$ is a subgroup and $M<\Phi(N)M$, so $\Phi(N)M=G$. Then we have $$N=G\cap N = \Phi(N)M \cap N=\Phi(N)(M\cap N)$$since $M\cap N<N$, consider the maximal group $H$ containing $M\cap{N}$ in $N$, we have $\Phi(N)\leq H$ and $M\cap N\leq H$ so $$N=\Phi(N)(M\cap N)\leq H <N$$
a contradiction, thus we proved that every maximal subgroup of $G$ contains $\Phi(N)$, so we get
$$\Phi(N)\leq\Phi(G)$$

But I have no idea about how to construct an example where $N$ is not normal in $G$ and the containment doesn't hold. I have listed some common groups such as $D_{2n},S_n,Q_8,Z_n$ but in many cases the work of computing the Frattini group subgroup is not straightforward, especially for $S_n$, and usually this will take lots of time to enumerate such groups one by one, and I can't get much information from the proof of the former statement, my question is:

**1. How to construct a counterexample for this problem?**

**2. How to work more efficiently when constructing examples in group theory or abstract algebra?** This question may sound somewhat abstract and I know that there is no panacea for math discovery, however I think that in the old and well developed math area, namely the basic abstract algebra there may be some experience that could minimize unnecessary work of beginners.

**3. Is there any advice for improving the question?**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun That's good advice in general, but I don't think that it makes much sense to ask a separate Question "Is there any advice on improving my previous question" :).

Comment: Fair enough, @DerekHolt. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perhaps an answer to Question 2 with reference to Question 1, but without answering Question 1 explicitly.

An obvious (I hope) idea of where to start is to look for a group $G$ with $\Phi(G)=1$ containing a subgroup $N$ with $\Phi(N) \ne 1$.

An equally obvious class of examples $G$ with $\Phi(G)=1$ is the class of (finite) simple groups.

Now every finite group $N$ embeds in a simple group $A_n$ for some $n \ge 5$, so we just need to find any finite group $N$ with $\Phi(N) \ne 1$ and then embed it into a suitable $A_n$.